# Is there a name for explaining or discussing a topic from various viewpoints/perspectives?

Tags: debate

When someone explains or discusses a topic intermitently switching to various persperctives, which are previously defined and named.

I've seen this often, e.g. in Shelly Kagan's course [Death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2J7wSuFRl8&list=PLR92_Ug0BfrWdm2Lx43dovuZLd-GCpYpb) or Michael Sandel's course [Justice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBdfcR-8hEY&list=PL30C13C91CFFEFEA6).

e.g. "From the physicalist view, we can say so and so. And from the dualist view, we can say such and such."

The speaker is not really mentioning their own perspective at all, but rather, making each statement as a function of a specific pre-defined perspective. You are not really commiting to something being true, but rather, something being true from a given perspective.

I love this thing, and I try to put it into practice often. But... does it have a name?

**edit:** I know some people may perceive this as a bad thing, as being dishonest, weaselly and deceptive, etc. --- To be clear: I don't seek to discuss any of that at this time. I'm just looking for a name, if there is any.

Comment: Not strong enough for an answer, but check the concept of "consilience". It is more about reaching conclusions than viewing things from various perspectives - or rather "domains", but it might nonetheless refer to what you are looking for. BTW, nice question.

Comment: @causative Academic philosophy is all about understanding and being able to paraphrase philosophical standpoints of others. It is an important skill to even be able to form a position of your own in the first place and even more important when it comes to teaching. Please stop imposing your view on others.

Comment: @Olaf Not an exact answer, but I appreciate the input nevertheless!

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Thank you for speaking out. I agree 100% with your assessment.

Comment: See [perspectivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspectivism) which is often misinterpreted as a form of [relativism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativism) or as a rejection of objectivity entirely...

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yes, it is an important skill to be able to paraphrase what others say - *because otherwise we cannot discuss and criticize it with our own views.* OP is talking about "not really mentioning their own perspective at all," i.e. *stopping* at describing some perspective and not analyzing it further. The analysis, involving the introduction of your own judgment, is the entire point, including in academic philosophy.

Comment: @causative The OP is talking about philosophy courses. It is their *job* to present philosophical perspectives on several problems to the best of their ability *without* influencing their students with their own (educated) opinion on the matter. A professor who talks down every philosophical position but their own in courses is nothing but incompetent.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Do you think the OP is himself a professor in a philosophy course? When he says "I love this thing, and I try to put it into practice often," he is not talking about he himself teaching a philosophy course. He's most likely talking about exactly the kind of thing I am describing, using it to support a view in debate without having to justify it himself. Of course, it is appropriate for a teacher in a philosophy course to describe what different philosophers thought. It is not appropriate for the students to use this as a substitute for justifying their own views.

Comment: @causative This is completely irrelevant to the question as it stands. It asks for a term. Your opinion on whether it is appropriate or philosophy or whatever to do that does not add anything here. It is not on you to tell people what they are allowed to do or ask.

Comment: @superiggy, it's pluralism, albeit not a committed semantic example so much as a pragmatic one ("for the purpose of this discussion" & similar phrases). Of course, a pluralist about pluralism-vs.-monism will tend to sound less dogmatic than a semantic commitment would push one towards. ---Also consider "overlapping consensus" and "common ground" (that last one shows up in religious apologetics, at least).

Comment: Collective analytical brainstorming. or groupthink. Dynamic collective analysis.

Answer (score 4):

This seems a form of [passive learning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_learning), where information is just presented, and the learner should take its own conclusions. But passive learning does not focus on multiple perspectives, just on passively presenting information.

If the explainer makes judgements, this ends up being the [dialectical method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectic). This last specifically addresses multiple points of view/sources of information, but is not what you search since it is intended to lead judgements.

Comment: It's contrasted with dialectic. Dialectic is all about putting forth what you personally think and why, and analyzing what the other person thinks and why.

Comment: @causative Dialectics are about putting antithetical propositions against each other and solving the juxtaposition either by dismissing one side, or synthesis, or reformulation. Nothing more, nothing less. In any case, it *always* involves taking other positions seriously and considering them carefully, no matter which use or historical period we speak about.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The topic was the dialectical method in debate, not Hegelian dialectics. The point of dialectic is that you do not merely describe what someone else thinks, but that the participants analyze and criticize it and compare it with their own views. They take a stand. Of course, you need to understand what the other person thinks, or what a third party thinks, but if you only say that and do not say what *you* think, you are not participating in dialectic.